# How do I get a replacement PTFE tube to fit inside my nozzle?

Tags: hotend, nozzle, ptfe-tube

I have been getting clogs and believe that it may be due to a damaged PTFE tube inside my hot end.  I have a replacement (it came with my printer), but I can't seem to fit the tube into the nozzle.

I also tried to turn the original PTFE tube around, and I can't get the other end to fit into the nozzle either.

Is there a trick to it?

Comment: pictures would be helpful.

Comment: Please add some more details to this question, such as what nozzle/hotend you have, and what PTFE tube you are trying to use as a replacement (which printer did it come with? what is the diameter?). For now, I am voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking". Even though you have provided a self-answer, that self-answer isn't useful to anyone without the question being clearly specified.

Comment: This unanswered question has been bumped to the homepage. Could you mark one of the answers (presumably your own) as accepted, to remove this question from the Unanswered Question list. We are still in Beta, and need to keep our stats up. Also, as the comments say, if you could expand upon the question and answer that would be most helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to get the tube in the nozzle.

It took a lot of patience, and it seems to help if the nozzle is warm as well.

Comment: If the nozzle (or throat) is warm, then it will have expanded, thus making it easier, in the same way if one warms a pickle jar lid, it will come off much easier.

Comment: Neither this nor the original question contain any quantifiable information

Answer (score 0):

What kind of printer do you have? Is it a FlashForge? They sell replacement PTFE tubes on their website, and you can also buy them on Amazon. Just be careful you are buying the correct tube for the correct printer. For example, the Flashforge Finder does not use the same size PTFE tube as the Flashforge Creator Pro or Flashforge Dreamer.

If you had trouble once, you can bet you will probably have trouble again. You should probably buy the part now before you need it. I tell you this as I sit without a working printer (and I have three) while I wait for parts.

Just be sure you buy the correct size tubing.

Comment: Welcome to the group.  On answering a question like this, it is better to make the Answer more general as opposed to proposing a solution for a specific printer (unless the OP says he has that printer).  You could use your specific printers as an example; but, describe the solution more generally. Adding how to measure the tube to find the correct size would be a nice touch.

Comment: @markshancock Unfortunately, the OP didn't specify the printer they were working with and this type of part can be specific to the machine (depending on the extruder assembly). Also note that Janice has a low reputation and therefore cannot create comments. I feel that this answer provides adequate details on how to solve a problem given the provided information.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the few pennies, I'd buy the threaded tube with the PTFE already in from any internet auction site.