# I need assistance replacing the PTFE tube in the nozzle on our Flashforge dreamer

Tags: ptfe-tube, flashforge, flashforge-dreamer

We disassembled everything in order to unclog the filament from the tube, but now I can't seem to get the nozzle to screw back in to the hotbed with the PTFE tube in place. Is there some kind of trick? I feel like if the tube were slightly smaller in diameter it would work. I'm using the same tube, just without the filament that had clogged it. Am I just not using enough force?

[image]

Comment: The PTFE-tube usually passes some kind of clip or clasp that allows it to only wander in one direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a replacement PTFE tube to fit inside my nozzle?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/how-do-i-get-a-replacement-ptfe-tube-to-fit-inside-my-nozzle)

Comment: Do you mean hotend and not *hotbed*?

Comment: Carl - I did indeed do several searches for how to do this - which is how I ended up on this page. I have not been able to find an answer, which is why I posted. The page that you linked to, doesn't actually answer the question and was not of use to me, which is why I posted my question with details and a picture.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix my problem so thought I'd post how I solved it for anyone else that is looking for a possible answer:

I believe the actual problem was that there was filament hardened inside the nozzle which I couldn't see, so that prevented me from being able to push the PTFE tube into the nozzle deep enough. I reassembled the extruder and heated it up, then using needle nose pliers so I wouldn't burn myself, I held the nozzle to the end to block to heat it up, (I didn't actually screw it in) and the stuck filament melted so I could scrape it out. I also learned from Tang, the Amazon flashforge tech guy, that the tube should be 23mm above the block, so that was helpful to use as a guide. As I read in other places, I then inserted the tube into the block to heat it up, which I think made it slightly more pliable and easier to insert into the nozzle.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to post an answer on your own question! Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue before. When you tried to push out the material from the tube, one end of the tube was being pressed. The tube was so soft that the diameter at that end was slightly increased. Hence it was difficult to put the tube back. When you tried to tighten the screw, more force applied and the tube end was pinched more. I got some spare tubes from the supplier. I simply replaced the tube. The PTFE tube could be pulled off from the nozzle.